# Elasaticsearch 650 million records optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

I try to figure out what solution is best for elasticsearch if my records will scale up to 658 million records per year. Actually now I have one index for all my records with 2 shards and 0 replicas. Also, I noticed that with 356k records and one index the sorting and searching are working faster than 365 indexes which have 1000 records. The question is, what is the best and faster way store the data in elastic for 658million records if I am going to sorting searching, and deleting records or indexes older than one year?

Elasticsearch 6.2 version, javascript api.

```
const defaultPageSize = 10
const indexTemplateSettings = {
    number_of_shards: 2,
    number_of_replicas : 0,
    max_result_window: 1000000000,
    'index.routing.allocation.enable': 'all',
}

const createClient = () =>
    new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: `${config.elastic.host}:${config.elastic.port}`,
        log: config.elastic.logLevel,
        httpAuth: `${config.elastic.userName}:${config.elastic.password}`,
    })

export const get = ({index, skip = 0, pageSize = defaultPageSize, search, sort = {by: 'timestamp', direction: 'desc'}}) => new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
        logger.silly(`getting data from elastic: index: ${index}, skip: ${skip}, pageSize: ${pageSize}`)

        let client = createClient()

        const sortSettings = {
            order: `${sort.direction.toLowerCase()}`,
            missing: '_last',
            unmapped_type: 'long',
        }

        const params = {
            from: skip,
            size: pageSize || undefined,
            index: `${index.toLowerCase()}`,
            filter_path: 'hits.hits._source, hits.total',
            body: {
                query: {'match_all': {}},
                sort: {
                    [`${sort.by}.keyword`]: sortSettings,
                    [`${sort.by}.seconds`]: sortSettings,
                },
            },
        }

        if (search) {
            params.body.query = {
                query_string : {
                    query: `*${search}* OR *${search}`,
                    analyze_wildcard: true,
                },
            }
        }

        await client.search(params,
            (e, {hits: {hits:  data = [], total: totalCount} = {hits: [], total: 0}} = {}) => {
                logger.silly(`elastic searching completed. Result: contains ${totalCount} items`)

                resolve({items: data.map(t => t._source), totalCount})
            })
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
})

export const push = (message, type) => new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
        let client = createClient()
        let oneYearAgoTime = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1)).toISOString().substring(0, 10)
        let indexCreationTime = new Date('2016-04-27').toISOString().substring(0, 10)

           await client.deleteByQuery({
            index: type.toLowerCase(),
            body: {
                query: {
                    range: {
                        '_timestampIndex' : {
                            lte: oneYearAgoTime,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        } , (error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Deleted of data completed', response)
        })

        await client.index({
            index: type.toLowerCase(),
            type,
            body: {
                ...message,
                _timestampIndex: indexCreationTime,
            },
        },
        (error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of data completed', response)

            resolve(response)
        })

    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you share the output of _cat/indices of you cluster? The index size in GB is relevant for choosing the right shard number. Also, how many nodes do you have in your environment?

Comment: 1.green open call N7CbN9RMTYuUxU3Hegoq9Q 2 0 1608588 0 332.9mb 332.9mb
2. now I have one node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 1,000 documents per shard is way too low. As a rule of thumb, a shard should be in the GB range; depending on the use case somewhere between 10GB (search) up to 50GB (logs) — given you have a properly sized machine.
   If I see that correctly in your comment you have 1,6 million documents, which need 333MB of storage space. Thus you'll have approximately 400 times as many documents, so around 133GB of data; maybe 10 shards? If you want to properly benchmark this, use 1 shard and see when it blows up — that should give you an idea about the maximum shard size.
2. Deleting documents from an index will always be costly. Time-based indices (if your shards are large enough) or filters (maybe even a [filtered alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) for the right amount of time) might allow you to avoid deleting lots of documents on a frequent basis.